# Accessing value of a global variable using require?

Tags: perl

Is it possible to access value of a global variable declared, in another perl script using require?

eg.

Config.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

our $test = "stackoverflow"
```

Main.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use stricts;

require "Config.pl"

print "$test\n";
print "$config::test\n";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sure.  The way you have suggested *almost* works.  Try:

`Config.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

our $test = "stackoverflow";
```

and the main program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;  

require "Config.pl";

our $test;

print "$test\n";
```

When you call `require`, the file is executed in the same namespace as the caller.  So without any namespaces or `my` declarations any variables assigned will be globals, and will be visible to the script.

Comment: `use vars` has been declared obsolete. It has been superseded by `our`.

Comment: @Borodin, `use vars` is not obsolete despite documentation to the contrary.

Comment: @ikegami: can you back that up somehow please? It is certainly more clumsy that using `our` and has the same effect.

Comment: @Borodin, No, it doesn't have the same effect. Any claims of clumsiness are your opinion, and that of whoever patched vars.pm, but it's not held by all the porters.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the variable `$test` in `Main.pl` by writing

```
our $test;
```

as you do in `Config.pl`. Then everything will work as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use a module:

`MyConfig.pm`: (There's a core package called "Config" already.)

```
package MyConfig;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw( import );

our @EXPORT_OK   = qw( $test );
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( ALL => \@EXPORT_OK );

our $test = "stackoverflow";

1;
```

`main.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyConfig qw( :ALL );
print "$test\n";
```

Comment: Should be "package MyConfig;" I think.

Comment: @Bill Ruppert, ack!, thanks. Talk about undermining my own point. Fixed.